# IWebDriver cannot access some site?

Tags: c#, selenium

I use a selenium `IWebDriver`, therefor I use a proxy.

Some of the website I access are blocked, for example

https://us.sunpower.com

I noticed it is blocked no matter the browser. I never had problems before this particular site. I'm lost as to what make a certain site being blocked?

I'm not an expert when it comes to proxy. So far the only solution I've been able to find is to deactivate the proxy. This doesn't help because I need the proxy in this case.

I found another clue which is to accept untrusted certificate, which doesn't seem to be the case right now. I added this property to my `IWebDriver` for Firefox:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.AcceptUntrustedCertificates = true;
```

However, this didn't change anything.

Is there a way to lower proxy security settings? I validate all the website I visit, so I trust them all.

Comment: Have you checked it manually by applying the proxy to your connection and then using another browser, maybe Chrome, if you're able to open the website. The problem might lie with the proxy.

Comment: yep, every broser I use Iget connection reset error

Comment: I meant checking it "manually". Are you able to access those websites when your system is connected to the same proxy ?

Comment: yep event if I navigate without my program, I get the same result.

Comment: I guess you'll need to change the proxy or try not using a proxy ?